# MSVC2013 - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, qt-creator, qt5.4

I recently installed the Qt add-inn for visual studio 2013. When I build a project in either Qt Creator or Visual Studio using MSVC2013 it builds without errors, but can only be run from inside the IDE. If I try to run it by clicking the .exe, it gives an error: "The procedure entry point ?qt_metacast@QMenuBar@@UAEPAXPBD@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library".

From the research I have done online, I found that it could be something to do about adding the correct .dll files in my .exe directory. Which .dll files do I need or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

I installed the [Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4 for Qt5](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-7) from the Qt website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DLL`s for this kind of libraries use to be unnecessarily big. You should make a Qt static compilation so that your needed functions are embed into your `*.exe`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I have to reinstall Qt or recompile or something else?