# DLL entry point not found Qt 5.6 with OpenCV 3.0.0

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator, opencv3.0

I have an anoying error while running a simple OpenCV application inside QtCreator. First of all: I'm using MSVC2013 64bit, build Qt5.6 and OpenCV3.0.0 with Cuda and Qt by myself. I tested the build inside MSVC2013 and it just worked fine.
Now switching to QtCreator I added the INCLUDEPATH and LIBS to a normal C++ project, saved the .pro file and run qmake. Worked.
Now I included the highgui.hpp, core.hpp and coded the simple image loading and showing app. See code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cv::Mat Image;
    cv::namedWindow("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

Now you're wondering why I didn't load any image. Well I could track down the error with the cv::namedWindow.
After I build the project I run the debugger and suddenly I get this error in a separate window:

```
The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: exception at 0x7ffa6f8dc4e0, code 0xc0000139:
DLL entry point not found, flags=0x1 (Execution cannot be continued)
```

I can build the project but I can't run it. As I said, I can build and run the very same application in MSVC2013 IDE without any errors. I've searched the web but it seems like I'm the only one with this problem.

Here is my .pro code

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OpenCV300C\\include \
    C:\\OpenCV300\\include\\opencv \
    C:\\OpenCV300\\\include \\opencv2

LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV300\\x64\\vc12\\lib \
    -lopencv_calib3d300d \
    -lopencv_core300d \
    -lopencv_features2d300d \
    -lopencv_flann300d \
    -lopencv_hal300d \
    -lopencv_highgui300d \
    -lopencv_imgcodecs300d \
    -lopencv_imgproc300d \
    -lopencv_ml300d \
    -lopencv_objdetect300d \
    -lopencv_photo300d \
    -lopencv_shape300d \
    -lopencv_stitching300d \
    -lopencv_superres300d \
    -lopencv_ts300d \
    -lopencv_video300d \
    -lopencv_videoio300d \
```

I'm using Win8.1, MSVC2013 64bit, Qt5.6 and OpenCV3.0.0 (own build)

As I'm sure the build of OpenCV and Qt is correct, I'm suspecting an error by myself. But I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.
Interesting enough I'm able to show the picture via Mat and the put it to a QImage and show it on a label via Pixmap. But I want to know, why cv::namedWindow is not working.

Also I noticed in another thread that I have to build Qt static.
[MSVC2013 - Entry Point Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902289/msvc2013-entry-point-not-found)

Is that the way to go?

EDIT:
Now things started to get interesting. I am actually able to run the program build by qt from outside of QtCreator (by just running the .exe from the explorer). So I'm pretty sure everything is fine. However there has to be a problem with QtCreator while running the Application. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and I want to share the issue with you, in case someone runs into the same problem.

I changed in the Projects tab under running environment the running environment from "build environment" to "System environment" (I guess that's the english name for it, since my IDE is German). Now I can run the App from inside the IDE and I'm pleased.

I haven't found out where the problem exactly is but for now I'm satisfied.